# Docker set environment variable from command or file

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I need to set an environment variable `CLASSPATH`. In that variable I need to set the result of a command:

```
hadoop classpath --glob
```

This will return a ton of java libraries and they all need to get set into that `CLASSPATH` variable. The big problem is that I can only run this command after the docker build is complete, meaning I have to do it in the `ENTRYPOINT`. But I just cant get it working. I tried differen approaches:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "export CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath --glob) ...."
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "set CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath --glob) ...."
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath --glob) ...."
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "/bin/bash && export CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath --glob) ...."
```

But nothing of it is working. The command itself is working, I tested it using:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "echo $(hadoop classpath --glob) >> /tmp/classpath.tmp ...."
```

This file contains the correct content after startup. So there is just a problem with setting and persisting the environment variable. How am I supposed to set the environment variable? Usually you use something like

```
ENV CLASSPATH="some classpath"
```

But here I cant use the `ENV` statement since it wont process the command `$(hadoop classpath --glob)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case I would prefer to use a bash profile change the `SHELL` to `sh -lc` instead of `sh -c`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine
RUN echo "export NAME=TARUNLALWANI" >> ~/.profile
RUN echo $NAME
SHELL ["sh", "-lc"]
RUN echo $NAME
CMD env
```

**Output of build**

```
$ docker build . --no-cache
Step 1/6 : FROM alpine
Step 2/6 : RUN echo "export NAME=TARUNLALWANI" >> ~/.profile
Step 3/6 : RUN echo $NAME

Step 4/6 : SHELL sh -lc
Removing intermediate container a6a243f24519
Step 5/6 : RUN echo $NAME
TARUNLALWANI
Successfully built 054f35a4d89a
```

As you can see changing the SHELL from `sh -c` to `sh -lc` starts loading our profile. So you will update the `.profile` to export `CLASSPATH` based on

**Running the container**

```
$ docker run 054f35a4d89a
HOSTNAME=92c4ca32b1f0
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
PAGER=less
PS1=\h:\w\$
NAME=TARUNLALWANI
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
CHARSET=UTF-8
```

**Edit-1**

Try this without the need of a profile

```
ENTRYPOINT []
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "export CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath --glob) && env"]
```

Comment: Then change the shell at very last command in your Dockerfile

Comment: Finally a fix for this

Answer (score 1):

The only working solution for that problem was to not use an `ENTRYPOINT` in the `Dockerfile` at all.

1. Create entrypoint.sh
2. Add all the stuff you need (exports for example) into that sh file
3. Copy entrypoint.sh in dockerfile to `/`
4. Execut entrypoint.sh in docker run or dockercompose

Attention: you need to execute it by `. /entrypoint.sh`. Otherwise it wont work.